# javascript animate border of a card to show progress

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, ionic-framework, progress-bar

Hi I'm want to create a card like element (like ionic) using the circumference of the rectangular card as progress bar.
I know that using svg paths I can animate progress bars with custom shapes.

Is there a way to make the the path responsive to the cards width and height? (both svg or non svg solutions are welcome)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```js
let prog = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 
  if (prog > 100) {
    return;
  }
  let loader = document.getElementById('loader');
  loader.style.height = "" + prog + "%";
  prog += 1;
}, 100);
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#loader {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 0px;
  width: 3px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div id="loader">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit1:**

You can generate an SVG that covers a given DOM element *(rectangular)* like this:

```js
let cardRect = document.getElementById('card').getBoundingClientRect();
let svgRect = document.getElementById('rect');
svgRect.parentElement.setAttribute("height", cardRect.height);
svgRect.parentElement.setAttribute("width", cardRect.width);
svgRect.setAttribute("height", cardRect.height);
svgRect.setAttribute("width", cardRect.width);
```

```css
#card {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <svg>
    <rect id="rect" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:orangered"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Then you can animate it using something like [Progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/)

**Edit2:** 
If you for some reason need the svg to be a path element *(Instead of a rect element)* [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/L7o6s1qa/2/) could work. *(It has to be on JSfiddle, for some reason it won't work on SO)*

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this does only animate one border. I could animate 4 border separately and control them together, but i though using svg paths might be more elegant?

Comment: Ohh, I thought you meant that you didn't want to use svg.

Comment: @HanChe So you want to use SVG, but you want to generate a custom SVG path based on the shape of a certain DOM element?

Comment: jep, i mean it's gonna be a rectangular card but what i need is for the svg path to be responsive sind in mobile view, the cards width and height are difference depending on the device

Comment: @HanChe I've changed my answer. If that doesn't help, then I'm afraid this is outside my knowledge.